# using datepicker with different UI-theme than the rest of the site

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using Jquery ui in my asp.net web application. I am using customized version of jquery UI. Now, I need to modify calendar css (jquery ui datepicker). I want to use theme rollover and get only css/images/js related to new look of datepicker only something like this:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-datepicker-with-different-ui-theme-than-the-rest-of-the-site

What steps do I need to take to customize my datepickedr only. Also, when datepicker is customized, I will include two jquery ui css ?

Please suggst

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using another jquery plugin, so you don't break or conflict styles within the app, a few examples [Jquery Calendar Plugins](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-calendar-plugins/)

Also you could try using CSS Namespacing to use styles on specifc elements like:

```
.containerClass .datepicker { ... !important }
.containerClass .ui.header { ... !important}
etc...
```

The bad is that you have to do it manually for all the classes the datepicker uses. Use **!important** so the styles prevail, although it's not considered a good practice.